# Can we get links to questions from the "select the next badge" screen?

Tags: feature-request

When we have a "next tag badge" selected we can click on it to go to a list of questions to answer. On the other hand though when we go into the screen to select a different badge there is no way to do so.

It would be nice to be able to click on badges from that screen to go to the list of relevant questions rather than needing to select one, leave the screen, and then click.